# kik url scheme to send messages

Tags: kik

I cannot find any information about kik url schemes for some reason.

I did find the following here on stackoverflow:

kik://

kik://users/username/profile

card://mywebsite.com/

cards://mywebsite.com/

I went to their android app manifest file and found the following code:

```
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
 <data android:host="kik.com" android:pathPrefix="/send/" android:scheme="kik-share"/>
</intent-filter>
```

I tried using kik-share// but it doesn't work

I tried the following too:

kik://send/title/text

kik://send?title=title&text=text

Answer (score 1):

The Kik Share API is available here: https://github.com/kikinteractive/kik-api-android

Comment: Their api is useless since I need to use it inside an android app or inside their browser.

Comment: There is an iOS SDK as well. Where are you trying to send messages from exactly?